# Using a regex with 'or' operator and getting matched groups?

Tags: c#, regex

I have some string in a file in the format

```
rid="deqn1-2"  
rid="deqn3"  
rid="deqn4-5a"  
rid="deqn5b-7"  
rid="deqn7-8"  
rid="deqn9a-10v"  
rid="deqn11a-12c"
```

I want a regex to match each **deqnX-Y** where **X** and **Y** are either ***both integers*** or ***both combination of integer and alphabet*** and if there is a match store **X** and **Y** in some variables.
I tried using the regex `(^(\d+)-(\d+)$|^(\d+[a-z])-(\d+[a-z]))$`
, but how do I get the values of the matched groups in variables?
For a match between two integers the groups would be (I think)

```
Groups[2].Value 
Groups[3].Value
```

and for match between two integer and alphabet combo will be

```
Groups[4].Value
Groups[5].Value
```

How do I determine which match actually occured and then capture the matching groups accordingly?

Comment: won't this `deqn(\w+)-(\w+)` solve your problem? if you want to know which match occurred you can use if else condition

Comment: @rock321987 `deqn(\w+)-(\w+)` will match `rid="deqn4-5a" ,rid="deqn5b-7"` also, I only want the **digit-digit** matches and get the values of each **digit** or the **digitAlpha-digitAlpha** matches and get each of their value in variables..

Comment: if there is digit-digit match or digitAlpha-digitAlpha match, do you want to keep the matched data in same capturing groups?

Comment: yes...is that possible?

Comment: i was thinking to use branch reset i.e. `(?|)` but its not supported in C#

Comment: so how do I do this?

Comment: right now I can think of only `if else` as an alternative.. maybe someone else can help

Comment: Do you mind showing the `if else` version?

Comment: To determine which match actually occurred, just test which ones are empty...

Answer (score 3):

As branch reset`(?|)` is not supported in C#, we can use named capturing group with **same name** like

```
deqn(?:(?<match1>\d+)-(?<match2>\d+)|(?<match1>\d+\w+)-(?<match2>\d+\w+))\b
```

[**`regextester demo`**](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=deqn%28%3f%3a%28%3f%3cmatch1%3e%5cd%2b%29-%28%3f%3cmatch2%3e%5cd%2b%29%7c%28%3f%3cmatch1%3e%5cd%2b%5cw%2b%29-%28%3f%3cmatch2%3e%5cd%2b%5cw%2b%29%29%5cb&i=deqn1-2%0d%0adeqn3%0d%0adeqn4-5a%0d%0adeqn5b-7%0d%0adeqn7-8%0d%0adeqn9a-10v%0d%0adeqn11a-1%0d%0a)

**C# code**

```
String sample = "deqn1-2";
Regex regex = new Regex("deqn(?:(?<match1>\\d+)-(?<match2>\\d+)|(?<match1>\\d+\\w+)-(?<match2>\\d+\\w+))\\b");

Match match = regex.Match(sample);

if (match.Success) {
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["match1"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["match2"].Value);
}
```

[**`dotnetfiddle demo`**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/I5Lgd9)

Answer (score 0):

You could simply *not care*. One of the pairs will be empty anyway. So what if you just interpret the result as a combination of both? Just slap them together. First value of the first pair plus first value of the second pair, and second value of the first pair plus second value of the second pair. This always gives the right result.

```
Regex regex = new Regex("^deqn(?:(\\d+)-(\\d+)|(\\d+[a-z])-(\\d+[a-z]))$");
foreach (String str in listData)
{
    Match match = regex.Match(str);
    if (!match.Success)
        continue;
    String value1 = Groups[1].Value + Groups[3].Value;
    String value2 = Groups[2].Value + Groups[4].Value;
    // process your strings
    // ...
}
```